# ASP.NET Custom authentication handler

Tags: php, asp.net

We have a web app written by a third party in ASP.NET, we don't have access to the source code but do have access to the server it runs on. We now have had a new public website developed for us in PHP and need to add a login to the homepage that will allow users to access out ASP>NET app. Any ideas on the best way this can be achieved? Can we write a custom authentication handler to do this?

Comment: We just need the users to be able to login directly from the (PHP) website, but because this is on a different server it's not working. The PHP developer was trying to post the user details directly to the login form in our ASP.NET app.

Comment: So you are trying to authenticate from a PHP application over to the ASP.NET by POSTing the details to the login form?

Answer (score 0):

So authenticating from PHP by making a POST request to an ASP.NET application?  And without having code access?  AFAIK you'll be restricted to using HTTP methods rather than anything else to broker the request.

The key is making the POST operation and consuming the response from ASP.NET and passing that to the client-side.  I have tried this [before](http://blogs.vbcity.com/drydo/archive/2005/09/27/5556.aspx) but this was using an ASP Classic page with the request being generated from a winforms application.  The principal is reasonably easy, POST over the username, password and associated details; then write out the authentication cookies.  ASP.NET Forms Authentication will generate at least one cookie whose default name is '.ASPXAUTH', you may also find the session cookie ('ASP.NET_SessionId') depending on how the site handles sessions.  One nice way of monitoring things is using [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to see what is passed and returned back and forth.

However, the problem I can envisage is your PHP page will be writing out the cookie for the domain hosting your PHP code and if the two sites are not co-existing in the same primary domain then while you might successfully authenticate, the ASP.NET site will not be able to read cookie created from a different domain.  You might be able to get away with the php and ASP.NET servers running in the same sub-domain using the '[enableCrossAppRedirects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx#pagexplained0002_aspnetforms)' but this is something I'm not overly familar with.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try fiddler, unfortunately the servers are on different domains